# Saving Variables (Android)

Tags: android, variables

I have a variable that I would like to save and be able to restore when the viewer opens the app back up. I call this variable, count

```
private int count=0;
```

It changes every now and then through out my main activity. How can I save this after editing and changing it and be able to restore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lookup `SharedPreferences` in the documentation.

Comment: Could you explain how I could use this in my situation?

Comment: on onResume, you open the shared preferences, load an int (say, PREFERENCE_COUNT, default value 0) and set `count` to it. In onPause, you open the shared preferences, open an editor, put `count` into PREFERENCE_COUNT, and commit.

Answer (score 4):

Using this...

```
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_COUNT, 0);
    count = settings.getInt("count", count);
}
protected void onPause(){
   super.onPause();


  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_COUNT, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putInt("count", count);
  editor.commit();
}
```